# Trigonometry Unit Circle Tangent visualization

Tags: trigonometry

I’m really confused. I’m learning about the Unit Circle and have learned how the cos and sin can be represented on the Unit Circle. But, when I was going to learn how Tangent looked like I got two different visualizations, the first one is that the tangent is a straight line going up starting from the end of the radius. The second one shows a line starting from the right triangles top point ending out from the circle. How can Tangent be shown in two different ways like this and why?

**First image link:**

https://images.app.goo.gl/gFw4CPo9kcabzDQS6

**Second image link:**

https://images.app.goo.gl/D8A3kCwXCmzKK3828

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The target triangles in each figure have a leg of $1$, an angle of $\theta$ adjacent to that leg, and a right angle; by Angle-Side-Angle congruence, the triangles are identical, so their "other" legs (which have length $\tan\theta$) match. ... I personally prefer the second image, as it leads to a figure I call the Fundamental Trigonograph. (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3097285/409).)

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. To intuitively understand it, try imagine flip the whole graph so that one leg of the angle goes to the other leg and vice versa.

Comment: So they’re basically the same but Tan  can be visualized in two different ways or the so called fundamental trigonograph?

Comment: @kaized: "Fundamental Trigonograph" is my own term. (I call a picture of a trig relation a *trigonograph*. See, for instance, my [trigonography](https://trigonography.com) site.) I don't think it's caught on (yet). ... In any case, yes: the triangles are the same. Different ways of visualizing things can help keep the mind flexible, and may serve other goals. Eg, your 1st image show tangent (and could show cotangent) as *vertical* (and horizontal), leaving secant (and cosecant) to be diagonal;  the 2nd image reverses this. Verticals and horizontals may be easier for some people to see.

Comment: I think I get it now, the both triangles are congruent and therefore you can set up an equation. And the answer will be Tangent. Its easier to draw the one in the first picture and see that they have the same angle (θ) and the second picture shows the triangel horizontal , it doesent really matter wich one because they are just orienting the triangle differently. So it just comes down to your personal preference. The rest of the inverse trigonometric functions also have more than one geometric interpretation on the Unit Circle. Expect for Sin and Cos, if I’m not wrong.